# Saving $1 Each Day of the Week but Each Week the Amount Goes up by $1 [Assignment]

Tags: java

Let's say you are saving up to buy a new phone. For the first week, you save $1 each day. For the second week, you save $2 each day and so on each consecutive week you add $1 more. Meaning that for week 3 you would be saving $3 per day. For example, after 16 days you would have saved $27 ($7 from the first week, $14 for the second, and $6 for those two days of the third week). See the image below for a clearer explanation:
[image]

I want to write a program that calculates the total amount of money that has been saved after N days. Where N is a number of days that was inputted by the user. Below is my code but I am unsure of how to optimize it. It works assuming the maximum number of days can be entered is 14 but of course I want to write the program so that it can take any number of days. During my research I came across the formula n*(n+1)/2 but that only works if the money was saved on a weekly basis (eg $1 for the first week, $2 for the second, etc). As explained before, in my problem the money is saved on a daily basis. My code below: (I'm new to Java so the syntax might not be perfect)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        int days;
        int savings = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of days: ");
        days = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
            if(i < 7){
                savings++;
            }
            if(7 <= i && i <=14){
                savings++;
                savings++;
            }
    }

    System.out.println("Total Frank's savings (after " + days +" days): " + savings);
}

}
```

Comment: What you are actually asking here is how to convert a (mathematically complicated) recurrence relation into a [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).  That is fundamentally  a maths problem not a programming question.

Comment: My advice:  1) If you really want a solution, do the math yourself.  2) If you can't do the math, ask on a Maths stack exchange site.  3) Don't bother.  Assuming that your code produces the correct answer, it is just fine.  (It is a waste of time optimizing code that doesn't need to be optimized.)

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical operation which would turn the day number into a week number? So that days 0..6 are in week 1, 7..13 in week 2, etc? Maybe it's easier if you think of the weeks as being numbered 0..n

Comment: Ok, here's a hint.    `7*1 + 7*2 + 7*3 ... + 7*N = 7(1+2+3 +... N)`.    How do you compute the sum from `1 to N`?  Now all you have to do is worry about the last partial week (if one exists).

Comment: @StephenC You are completely right. Should've posted this on the Maths stack. If I would've known how to solve this then writing the code would not be a problem.

Comment: @WJS Thank you very much. I think I now understand the problem a little better. Computing the sum from ``1 to N`` would be simple with a ``for loop`` where I do something like ``for(int i = 0; i<=N;i++){sum+=i;}``. That times 7 would give me how much money has been saved for that amount of weeks.

Comment: At this point, I'm just going to suggest that you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  'Cos it should be simpler to write and debug a relatively simple loop than to do the maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int days = 16;
        int weeks = days / 7; // '/' means get the divider
        int savings = 0;
        int ans = 0;
        if (days % 7 == 0) {  // '%' means get the divider, when there's no reminder for day / 7
            for (int i = 1; i <= weeks; i++) {
                savings += 7 * i;
            }
        }
        else { // when there is reminder for day / 7
            for (int i = 1; i <= weeks; i++) {
                int left = days % 7;
                ans += 7 * i;
                savings = ans + (weeks + 1) * left;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("saving is " + savings);
    }
```

Comment: Friendly reminder from a 4th year CS student: sometimes you may print out the values of parameters from each step to test whether you get the correct result or not.

Comment: You don't need any loops for this.  It is  a math problem.

Comment: I dont think he/she needs to consider for time complexity, so as long as he/she gets the answer.

Comment: @April - Absolutely correct.  The indications are that the OP has been set this as a *programming* assignment rather than a *maths* assignment.  It seems to have been set to teach the OP how to write loops.  So unless the assignment requirements actually state that an `O(1)` solution is required, then an `O(N)` solution is 1) fine, and 2) probably what the teacher is looking for.

Comment: (It seems that the OP was having problems figuring out how to get the loops to work, and they thought they could shortcut the debugging of their looping code by finding and implementing a closed-form equation.  But that's the hard way to solve the problem ... for someone with only average maths skills.)

Comment: This works perfectly granted that the number of days is not below 7. Meaning that this does not work for less than one week since days / 7 would result in the variable ``week`` equaling 0.

Comment: @Rivf - I suggest that you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ... and debug this yourself.

Comment: @Rivf Thanks for advice, then please add if (days < 7) ... That part would be easy